# How can I find the shortest distance between a circle and a sphere?

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization, vectors

So basically I’m trying to create an optimization equation for finding the closest point to the intersection between 3 spheres that don’t actually intersect. My idea was to first find the circle created by the intersection of two spheres and then minimizing the distance from a point on the 3rd sphere to that circle.

If this method is wrong, I would greatly appreciate any ideas. For context, this is for GPS trilateration, where you derive position using distances from 3-4 satellites. Due to error these distances sometimes don’t fully match up so I’m trying to find the closest point

Thank you so much for your time

Comment: Does this point have to lie on any of the spheres? What if none of the spheres intersect each other? On the other hand, if the spheres do all intersect, there might be more than one intersection point. Which of these intersection points do you want?

Comment: Do **not** vandalize your posts. This may lead to a suspension or a ban.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about
$$\min_{x,y_i} \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^3 ||x-y_i|| : y_i \in S_i \right\},$$
where $S_i$ are the spheres. At the optimum, $x$ is the point you are interested in, and $||x-y_i||$ is the distance between $x$ and sphere $i$. Alternatively, you can minimize the maximum distance ($t$) instead of the sum of the distances:
$$\min_{t,x,y_i} \left\{ t : \sum_{i=1}^3 ||x-y_i|| \leq t, \; y_i \in S_i \right\},$$
Both optimization problems are second order cone problems, for which many methods are available.

Comment: Could you possibly recommend a method? I admit my knowledge is limited since I’m only in my last year of High School, but I would greatly appreciate your help

Comment: @SeyedRezaAhlesaadat Do you use Python or some other programming language? One time solve or many times?

Comment: @SeyedRezaAhlesaadat did you appreciate my answer?

Comment: Sorry I don't use any programming languages, I appreciate you taking your time but I'm still confused about the question :(

Comment: @SeyedRezaAhlesaadat the problem here is that there is not a simple formula. You need specialized software that runs instructions that college students learn only in their master's. Running the software is not so difficult if you know Python or Matlab.

Comment: Hi this is a beautiful answer why can't the mods allow us to star favorite answers?

Comment: @TomislavOstojich thank you for the compliment! It means more to me than a star.

Answer (score 0):

The spheres' centres lie in the same plane.  If you have done first-year uni maths, you can find an orthonormal basis for the plane, and reduce the problem to circles in the plane.